# Bay Window too far out?

Tags: windows, roof, leaking

I have a Bay Window that needs to be replaced due to leaking during heavy rain & general sagging/not level. Contractor confirmed it's an Andersen window from 1989. 3 double-hung windows sized as 1:2:1 ratio.

The top of the window goes beyond the eaves, past the gutter, and about 2 inches further. General Contractor says that is fine because a new window with proper installation/flashing would handle the rain. Local Window chain specialty store (not Home Depot/Lowes) sales guy said we have to bring it back a few inches to stay under the eaves. Driving around the neighborhood, I can only find 2-3 similar bay windows that stick-out like mine.

Window has no braces underneath. It's tied to the roof through cables.

Anyone with actual construction experience that can give me some advice on whether or not the window should be shortened to stay under the eaves or not? Since it didn't always leak, is it just an old window I can replace with the same size/properly installed flashing or was this improperly installed decades ago from prior owner and we've just been lucky thus far?

Comment: In situations like this a picture is invaluable. Please post one, or a few.   From a personal standpoint I have never in over 1/2 century seen a  bay window that extended farther than the roof line, unless it was covered by another roof.

Comment: I had Home Depo install a bay window some 30 Yers ago and newer had trouble with it

Comment: I would always rank a GC above a sales guy for authoritative statements. There should be a drip edge to shed water so that it doesn't run down your window. It sounds like this is what your GC is describing. The GC may have water damage in mind, however, whereas the sales guy has hard water stains in mind. Rainy climate? OCD about hard water stains? I would want an eave to shed water well away from the window. Dry climate? Happy with scummy windows? F-it.